# Does git pull affect remote tracking branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

As we know git pull = git fetch + git merge.  But my understanding with git merge is it only affects the branch that you are merging into, not the branch you are merging from.

So in the case of git pull, I imagine it looks like this:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

If that's the case, new changes from origin will be replayed on master, but origin/master will not have the changes committed to local master branch. Does git pull make sure remote tracking branch (origin/master) contain all the new changes made in master after git merge or is that done when you do git push?

Comment: If you merge branch B into branch A, you will need to push the changes to branch A's remote branch for the changes to show up there.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I mean.  I want to know when you are doing git fetch + git merge, whether the remote tracking branch is updated with changes from local.

Comment: If you have local changes, you could do a `git stash` to store your changes, then `git pull` to get changes from the remote branch, then `git stash pop` to re-apply your changes. Doing a `git pull` won't automatically apply local changes to the remote branch. You'd have to push them up yourself.

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix Thanks for answering - sorry your answer is not what I am asking.

Comment: BTW it's more accurate to say that changes on origin/master will be *merged into* master, not "replayed on" master.  On the other hand, if you set up fetch to use rebase instead of merge, *your* changes will be replayed (more precisely, copied a la `git cherry-pick`), but onto the new base commit as found on the new `origin/master` after the fetch step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is simple: no, the remote-tracking branch remains unaffected.

A good way to think about a remote-tracking branch like `origin/master` is that your git remains independent of their (origin's) git almost all of the time, except for when you tell your git to call up their git and coordinate.  The commands that do that—that call up the remote over the Internet-phone—are `git fetch` and `git push` (and of course the initial `git clone`).  Therefore, **`origin/master` is always "where `master` was on origin" as of the last time your git synchronized with it.**

When you fetch or push, *then* your git gets their git's idea of what all their branches are, and updates your remote-tracking branches.  It sets them to whatever the remote has at that time, provided that you also have those SHA-1 IDs.<sup>1</sup>  You can limit which branches your git updates, but the default for a straight `git fetch` is to get all the remote's current info.

There's one more command<sup>2</sup> that phones up the remote but doesn't update your git's remote-tracking branches: `git ls-remote` does the first step of a fetch or push, then simply displays all the reference names it gets from the remote.  Try it, it's purely informational but will let you see how this really works.

---

<sup>1</sup>Your git can't point your own remote-tracking branches to SHA-1s that you don't have.  Since `git fetch` normally brings everything over, it's the one that does the main updating.  With `git push` you ask the remote to *change* its SHA-1 IDs to something your git sends over, so if it says "yes" then by definition you also have those objects—but that's only guaranteed for the branches and/or tags you send over, not for other branches they have.

<sup>2</sup>Actually there are several, but just the one that's good to try out for illustration.  For completeness, I'll mention that `git remote show` will sometimes also phone up the remote.

Comment: So I take it that after git push, if you do git fetch again, the remote tracking branch will now contain the new changes in local?

Comment: If your `git push` succeeds your remote-tracking branch will *already* match whatever you pushed (because the remote agreed to set his branch to the ID you pushed).  For instance, if you say `git push origin 1234567:master` and you have a commit whose ID is `1234567` and the `push` succeeds, your `origin/master` will now contain `1234567`.  If you want to be sure, you can `git fetch origin` again to double-check, or use `git ls-remote origin` to view it.

Comment: Just to make sure - so what your answer is suggesting is that if I have new changes in local branch and server has new changes, after git fetch and git merge, my local branch will not be the same as my tracking branch (origin/master), right?

Comment: You're right. You haven't pushed your local changes to the remote branch so they will differ in that aspect.

Comment: @Boon: yes.  What's going on is that git likes to save just about *everything*, so it has all of *your* commits, and `fetch` adds all of *their* commits.  If you then make a new merge commit, only you have the new one (and only you have your previous ones) but you did get their commits, and your `origin/master` (still) tells you "where they were the last time we checked".  Once you push, you give them your commits, and ask them to set *their* master to point to *your* latest commit (which you just gave them).  If they say "ok", your git knows they now have what you gave them.